# Using Google Analytics on local intranet site without internet connection

Tags: intranet, google-analytics

I am wondering if there is a way to use Google Analytics on my works local intranet site. It's a WordPress site, and our IT dept doesn't allow the WordPress sites to connect to the internet . I am thinking no, but I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: If you can at work, install the Chrome browser and the [GA debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) and see if the tracking beacon is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit) Yes, you can use Google Analytics on your Wordpress Install.

It isn't the **server** that is connecting to the Google analytics service, but the **client's machine**.

If the client can connect to the internet, then google analytics will work unless that specific domain has been blocked by your company, which is unlikely.

Comment: all I know is that I can't use any plugins that need internet access to work because my company blocks internet access to the portion of the server that the site is on.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr - We're not talking about the server, but the client. I will update the answer.

Comment: Awesome. I guess my next question will be how to install it since I usually use the Google Analytics Plugin by Joost de Valk.

Comment: I suggest asking that question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/